# Create new module in Magento2 stable version?

Tags: magento2

As Stable version of Magento2 is released, how should we create a new module? What are the exact steps required to create a new module in Magento2 stable version ? Is there any way to convert Magento2 Beta module into stable version module ?

Looking forward to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a successful way to create a new module in stable Magento2 version:

Below are the list of files that you need to create in order to create a new module, my package name is **Ktpl** and module name is **Brandmanager** for this case.

1) Create module.xml at app/code/Ktpl/Brandmanager/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ktpl_Brandmanager" setup_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

2) Create composer.json at app/code/Ktpl/Brandmanager/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "ktpl/brandmanager",
  "description": "Brand manager adds the facility to manage store brands in Magento2",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/module-store": "*",
    "magento/module-backend": "*",
    "magento/framework": "*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "KTPL",
      "email": "chirag.bhavsar@krishtechnolabs.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Ktpl\\Brandmanager\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

3) Create registration.php file at app/code/Ktpl/Brandmanager/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ktpl_Brandmanager',
    __DIR__
);
```

After placing these files run below command from Magento root.

```
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generation/*
```

This process will successfully register your module and you would be able to see you module at store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced section.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. There are definitely inconsistencies in the Developer Doc examples between the beta and the stable version. This helped me out significantly.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to give you a step by step guide, this isn't the place for such a answer.

Most notable change recently are requiring a registration.php and  composer.json in the module route

Eg.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/composer.json

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/registration.php

I would just base your new module of the core, it is the easiest way.

Comment: See also http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build.html ... 1) prepare a directory structure, 2) Set up configuration, including registration, 3) order it, load it

Comment: I would accept your answer as it led me to a successful completion, thanks.